# How to close side nav when clicking elsewhere on the screen?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following script:

```
<script>
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "200px";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";      
  }
</script>
```

What should I implement to make it close each time the user clicks elsewhere on the screen?

Comment: I assume the side nav is outside the content div. So you could do
`<div onclick="closeNav()">...` on the div that has the rest of content.

Answer (score 1):

I have thought about this problem as well. A basic implementation is not hard but making sure it works all the time is.

The core idea is that we add an `onclick` event listener to the `window`. In that event listener we check the *target* node. If the target node is not within the nav container, we hide the nav:

```
window.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    if (contains(event.target, document.getElementById("mySidenav")) === false) {
        closeNav();
    }
});
```

For bonus points you can use the capturing phase to circumvent random other code that uses `event.stopPropagation()` to control event handling; stopPropagation means we won't see the event in the bubble phase. You'll still run into problems with code that does for instance `event.preventDefault()` in an `onmousedown` listener; which makes it so the `click` event doesn't spawn.

You will also want to add an exception for the element that opens the nav container. It should probably *close* the nav; with the method outlined so far it will close the nav and then open it again.

Answer (score 0):

in your js file

```
 function openNav() {

document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
document.getElementById("main-menu").style.marginLeft = "250px";

   }

 function closeNav() {

document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
document.getElementById("main-menu").style.marginLeft = "0";

  }

function test() {

var poswitdth = document.getElementById("mySidenav");

if (poswitdth) {
    var width = poswitdth.style.width;
    if(width == "250px")
    {
        closeNav();
    }

    else {
        openNav();
       }
     }
  }
```

in your html file !!!

```
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
      <a href="#">About </a>
      <a href="#">Services </a>
      <a href="#">Our Patners</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
      <a href="#">Carreers</a>
   </div>

  <div id="main-menu">
      <i  class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"   onclick="test()">Menu</i>
 </div>
```

This could help you